# For programmers, what's the most intuitive keyboard shortcut for switching between programming logic and unit tests?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, multitasking

I'm developing a browser-based application for programming and unit-testing. What's the best keyboard shortcut to switch between the programming pane and the unit-testing pane?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> would seem good to me, but that's for opening a new tab in the browser so I can't use that.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Testing gives an *alternative* look at your code. Also seems to be unassigned in my current browser FF. Haven't tested it in CH and IE thought.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let them choose their own shortcut?

There is no added benefit for each person to have a fixed shortcut, and many programmers have custom shortcuts for a number of applications.  Hence you're not going to find one that is universally useful.

Comment: A sane default should always be provided though?

Comment: It's common practice in browser-based apps not to allow choosing shortcuts. I agree it would be useful to, but an arbitrary selection of keys (depending on the browser) won't be allowed, which any interface needs to accommodate. Until that can be developed, I need to find a sensible default.